# Number of sequences of three colors if two elements of the same color must not be adjacent and blue must appear directly between red and green

Tags: combinatorics

We have a sequence of length $n$.

We can use three colors: $red$, $green$, $blue$.

1. Two elements of the same color must not be adjacent.
2. The blue stripe must be directly between the strips, one of which is green and the other - red (i.e. the incorrect flag is RGBG).

What is the number of sequences of length $n$?

Comment: Any ideas?  Usual thing would be to try to work recursively...reduce the problem to one for shorter strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a recurrence. For any $n > 0$ let $s_n$ be the number of sequences. $s_1$ = $s_2$ = 2 (check).

For $s_{n + 1}$ with $n > 1$, note that every valid $s_n$ corresponds to exactly one sequence of length $n + 1$; the $n$-length sequence ended in either red or green, so by appending the other one, we get $n + 1$. The only $n + 1$ cases we haven't accounted for, then, are those whose second-to-last element is blue, since these do not come from a valid $n$-coloring. Note that each element of $s_{n - 1}$ corresponds to exactly one such string; it ends in either red or green, so we append blue and then the complementary color. Thus the recurrence is $s_n = s_{n - 1} + s_{n - 2}$ with initial conditions $s_1 = s_2 = 2$, a Fibonacci-like sequence for which you can use similar techniques to find a closed-form formula.